# What does "ls" mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know the "xs" can be used for expressing the rest elements in a list
but I totally have no idea what the "ls" mean in Haskell?

Comment: If you're destructuring a list `(h::ls)` then it means the same thing. The `s` suffix is just a common convention for naming the tail of a list.

Comment: @Lee: in Haskell it's `(h:ls)`. The `::` is cons in ML, O'Caml, etc

Comment: "ls" has no intrinsic meaning in Haskell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` is not a predefined thing. It is whatever you bind it to, just like `xs`.

For instance, I think you've seen examples like this:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

The variable `xs`, that you just defined here, gets *bound* (will have the value of) the rest of the list because of the pattern `(x:xs)`. But this could equally well have been written as:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (l:ls) = l + sum ls
```

We prefer not to call a variable `l` though, because it is easily confused with the digit `1` (or even the pipe symbol `|` on really messed up fonts).

We could even write:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (head:tail) = head + sum tail
```

where we reuse the names of the built-in prelude functions `head` and `tail`, but this is bound to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The rule of thumb in haskell for naming variables that refer to lists is to add an *-s*, just like for regular plurals in English. So if you have ha list of `x` elements, you name it `xs`. If you have an `l`, a list of `l` will be  `ls`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `ls` instead of `xs` for special case of lists of **l**ists.

Comment: @benmachine: Maybe I've done too much web stuff, but I can't look at `xss` without think of cross-site scripting :P.

Answer (score 2):

It's the exact same thing. There's nothing special about the name xs; it's just convention to respectively name the head and tail of a list x and xs, a and as, l and ls, etc.